Force refresh of CSS counter calculation
I am integrating the Quill editor into our application, and have been asked to implement line-numbering in code blocks. Following from this discussion, I used
.ql-code-block-container {
    counter-reset: line;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.ql-code-block:before {
    counter-increment: line;
    content: counter(line);
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    color: #EEE;
}

This works well but for one issue in Chrome. I can add some text, which appears in Dev-tools as:
<div class="ql-code-block-container" spellcheck="false">
    <div class="ql-code-block">Here</div>
    <div class="ql-code-block">is</div>
    <div class="ql-code-block">some</div>
    <div class="ql-code-block">text</div>
</div>

and Crome renders as

But if I highlight and delete the middle two lines, Dev-tools shows
<div class="ql-code-block-container" spellcheck="false">
    <div class="ql-code-block">Here</div>
    <div class="ql-code-block">text</div>
</div>

while Chrome renders it as

If I add a new line of text, it seems to recalculate the counters correctly. I suspect this is a Chrome bug (it refreshes fine in FireFox), but is there any general way to force a browser to refresh its CSS counter calculations when content changes?

You can try to toggle counterReset in javascript to force chrome to refresh. Take a look a this example :


function remove() {
  console.log("remove")
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("ql-code-block");
  removeCodeBlocElement(els[1])
}


function removeCodeBlocElement(element) {
  var elementContainer = element.closest(".ql-code-block-container");
  element.remove();
  elementContainer.style.counterReset = "none"
  //using setTimeout to disable browser property optimisation
  setTimeout(() => { 
  elementContainer.style.counterReset = "";
  }, 0);
}
.ql-code-block-container {
  counter-reset: line;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.ql-code-block:before {
  counter-increment: line;
  content: counter(line);
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
<div class="ql-code-block-container" spellcheck="false">
  <div class="ql-code-block">Here</div>
  <div class="ql-code-block" id="remove">is</div>
  <div class="ql-code-block">some</div>
  <div class="ql-code-block">text</div>
</div>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>




Edit : If you have any events on your ql-code-block, you can also use innerHTML and avoid a possible flickering counter number


function remove() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ql-code-block");
  var element = elements[1];
  var elementContainer = element.closest(".ql-code-block-container"); 
  element.remove();
  //using innerHTML removes all events from child elements
  elementContainer.innerHTML = elementContainer.innerHTML;
}
.ql-code-block-container {
  counter-reset: line;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.ql-code-block:before {
  counter-increment: line;
  content: counter(line);
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
<div class="ql-code-block-container" spellcheck="false">
  <div class="ql-code-block">Here</div>
  <div class="ql-code-block" id="remove">is</div>
  <div class="ql-code-block">some</div>
  <div class="ql-code-block">text</div>
</div>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove using InnerHTML</button>



